# How do I align my lightning styled options in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, slds, selectlist, label, lightningstylesheets

I have a Visualforce page with a selectlist, an inputfield and some buttons. The Selectlist label is above the selection, which makes the alignment funny for the other fields. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
<fieldset class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">               
    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">                        
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control ">
                <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-3 ">
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-3 ">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="selobject">Select an Object</label>
                            <apex:selectList id="selobject" value="{!selobject}" size="1" label="Select an Object" title="Select an Object" styleClass="slds-select">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>   
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                        <div class="slds-file-selector slds-file-selector_files">
                            <div class="slds-file-selector__dropzone">
                                <apex:inputFile styleClass="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" onchange="handleFile(this)" accept="csv" id="importfile" value="{!csvFileBody}" filename="{!csvAsString}"/>
                                <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-file-selector__body" for="importfile">
                                    <span class="slds-file-selector__button slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                                        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#upload"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                        Select File
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="fileName" class="slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show">or Drop Files</span>
                                </apex:outputLabel>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" value="Import" action="{!importCSVFile}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a margin to this div below

```
<div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
```

like

```
<div class="slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-top_medium">
```